# passing object references by value in C#

Tags: c#

```
var test = new TestClass();

SomeMethod(test);
Console.WriteLine(test);

SomeMethod2(test);
Console.WriteLine(test);

Console.ReadKey();

void SomeMethod(TestClass a)
{
    a = null; 
    
}

void SomeMethod2(TestClass a)
{
    a.intThing = 1;

}

public class TestClass
{
    public int intThing =0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{intThing}";
    }
}
```

A bit confused on the output of this here - SomeMethod which passes in a and sets a=null does not modify the initial test object whatsoever, however setting the intThing field to 1 in SomeMethod2 modifies the initial test object. Whats going on with this? Why can't I set the test object to null in SomeMethod by passing it in? I know that the reference to test in memory is being passed by value into the methods - I'm just confused why setting a equal to null doesn't act on the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are passing reference to the object by value, `a` is just a local variable storing the reference to the object in memory and setting `a` to `null` will not affect other variables storing that reference. `a.intThing = 1;` in the second method on the other hand modifies the object by reference (i.e. both `test` and `a` point to the same place in memory and you change it).

You can use [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) to make the first snippet work as desired:

> When used in a method's parameter list, the `ref` keyword indicates that an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The `ref` keyword makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on the argument.

```cs
SomeMethod(ref test);

void SomeMethod(ref TestClass a)
{
    a = null;     
}
```

This will result in `test` set to `null`.

Read also:

- [Reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Answer (score 2):

You've set the reference to null. That doesn't have any effect on what the reference is pointing at.

If you want to pass the reference by reference, you can use the `ref` keyword:

```
var test = new TestClass();

SomeMethod(ref test);
Console.WriteLine(test);

SomeMethod2(ref test);
Console.WriteLine(test);

Console.ReadKey();

void SomeMethod(ref TestClass a)
{
    a = null; 
    
}

void SomeMethod2(ref TestClass a)
{
    a.intThing = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters themselves are usually always passed by-value. `void SomeMethod(TestClass a)` copies a reference onto the stack and you set the copied reference to `null`.

But if you access a member, you modify the referenced object instead.

Passing an object using the [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference) solves this and lets you actively modify the passed in reference itself.